# sybase For loop that consists of an Query for every result got from the select statement

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

```
SELECT distinct(a.acct_num)
FROM customer_acct a,
customer_acct_history b LIKE "%000%"    
WHERE a.acct_num *= b.acct_num AND acct_type='C'
```

Based on the Output of this query ,It returns a lot of customer account numbers . I am trying to do a select Query returning top 1 for every account number . I am planning to link the o/p of first query in the second sql like where a.acct_num=( output of first Query ) . I want to do this in a loop and select top 1 for every account number. Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Is a good place for the CURSOR use:

```
declare curs cursor
for 
SELECT distinct(a.acct_num)
FROM customer_acct a,
customer_acct_history b LIKE "%000%"    
WHERE a.acct_num *= b.acct_num AND acct_type='C'

OPEN curs 

DECLARE @acct_num INT

fetch curs into @acct_num

/* now loop, processing all the rows
** @@sqlstatus = 0 means successful fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 1 means error on previous fetch
** @@sqlstatus = 2 means end of result set reached
*/
while (@@sqlstatus != 2)
BEGIN
   SELECT Sometning FROM somwhere where @acct_num = ...
   fetch curs into @acct_num
END
```

GL!

Comment: can we do this just with the loops alone .since cursor brings in performance issues :)

Comment: You could always make a join with your original select. It would be the fastest and most elegant solution.

Comment: can you write a little snippet or syntax of how to go with joins . ? it would be help ful for me to proceed